# More elegant way to determine whether two floats have same signs in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, compare, signed

Is there any way that can compare the signs of the two floats quickly in C#? I doubt the performance of comparing a float with 0 again and again. However, it seems that bit operation of float is prohibited in C#, so we cannot use methods like (a^b)&0x80000000 or ((a >> 31) == (b >> 31)) to determine(Ignore the case of 0 here).

The problem about cast from float to int (without pointer) is rounding since every number that is smaller than 1 will be rounded as 0.

The problem about cast from float to int (with pointer) is only two possible returning values, unable to recognize 0.

It is the time now to test the performance of the combination of pre-judgement of 0 and cast with pointer.

(Deletions about the mistakes I've made here)

Comment: `Math.Sign(a) == Math.Sign(b)`? But `Sign` simply compares `< 0`, `> 0`, `== 0`

Comment: If you doubt the performance of "comparing it again and again", store the value in a bool. Of course this might be a case where you are doing micro-optimisations. Possibly something for the speed rant: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @john: I would trust in the ability of the Framework programmers and the JiT in this case. Just look at the kind of optimisations done for Array bounds checks: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr/

Comment: @Christopher I wasn't doubting them, I was just [stating a fact](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,571).

Comment: @john: I was thinking nearly in the same way.

Comment: @john: Good information. Of course what the sourcecode looks lke, what MSIL is generated from and how it looks after the JiT is done with it are three totally different maters :) Plus implementation details. I think CPU registers used to have a value for "sign", so ideally the code at runtime would just query that one.

Comment: @Christopher: Does not really help in my case. I am seeking for a way to compare signs for different pairs of floats.

Comment: @GuardHei: Make a struct consisting of the float and "sign" value (int seems to be what Math.Sign uses). Set the sign value when creating the instance. Ideally make the whole thing inmutable. Now you have two discoveries of the sign less in each comparision, at the cost of some upfront work.

Comment: @Christopher: Again, space vs speed, going to try that. Thanks.

Comment: The sign is the MSB bit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) so I would use following :             Single num = 1.23F;
            Boolean pos = ((Int32)num & 0x80000000) == 0 ? true : false;

Comment: @jdweng: Looks like read the bit data in the format of int32 to do bit operation?

Comment: @jdweng: Casting to `Int32` doesn't get you the IEEE-754 representation. Even if it did, that's only returning two options instead of three.

Comment: "Meanwhile, if a float approximately equals to 0(-float.Epsilon < number < float.Epsilon) and the other one is not" - which `float` values other than 0 do you expect to be able to find in that range? And what do you mean by "The reason that I don't use Math.Sign(float value) is simply because the comparisons it makes do not accept approximate values"? At the moment I find your too unclear to answer. (Given `EqualsInValue` though, I suspect you've misunderstood what `float.Epsilon` means.)

Comment: Actually this code I think is better.  Looks like in Net the bytes are reversed :             Single num = 1.23F;
            Boolean pos = (BitConverter.GetBytes(num).Last() & (byte)0x80) == 0 ? true : false;  See the source code at msdn which uses c++ : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs

Comment: @jdweng: If performance is a concern, creating a new byte array just to determine the sign doesn't sound like a good idea. (And this is still returning one of two values when a sign has three potential values. And it's not throwing an exception for NaN values which the OP appears to want.) Under what circumstances do you think this approach is better than using `Math.Sign`?

Comment: You always can use unsafe code :Boolean pos = (\*(int\*)&num) == 0 ? true : false; which in this case is always safe.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: I didn't misunderstood the meaning of Epsilon, but I just found logic was wrong. Thanks for pointing out it.

Comment: @jdweng: `Boolean pos = ((Int32)num & 0x80000000) == 0 ? true : false`  There are exceptions during the cast. Any float number that is smaller than 1 or larger than 1 will become +0 finally. The sign will always be positive.

Comment: @jdweng: And again, that's still going to treat any positive value as having the same sign as 0, which isn't the normal meaning of sign.

Comment: If you're comfortable with `float.Epsilon`, I still don't understand what you mean by "Meanwhile, if a float approximately equals to 0(-float.Epsilon < number < float.Epsilon) and the other one is not" - that's not just "approximately equal to 0" - that *is* equal to zero. There are no non-zero values such that `-float.Epsilon < number < float.Epsilon`. Fundamentally it's still unclear to me what you're asking. Please edit the question to make it a lot clearer, otherwise I suspect no-one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I should say that the Epsilon refers to the precision level that I want instead of the minimum acceptable difference of float number. Shouldn't be float.Epsilon but other const values that express a precision.

Comment: Right. That would make a lot more sense. It would really help if you'd edit the question again to provide concrete examples - and what your performance targets are. (If you don't *have* performance targets yet, now would be a good time to decide them, as otherwise you'll never know when you're "done".)

Comment: (a) Floating-point has +0 and -0. What results do you want when comparing -0 to +3 or -0 to +0? (b) Why do you think the compiler will not optimize comparisons into bit tests or other high-performing code if they are semantically equivalent?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Much less the processor and it's Float Processing Units. This kind of optimisation sounds like .NET was the wrong environment to begin with. To many layers of abstraction to ever get a definitive measurement or answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `unsafe`, you can convert the bits to an `int` using pointers and then you can do bitwise operations

```
*(int*)(&val1) >> 31 == *(int*)&val2 >> 31;
```

if you are worried about performance you can use [`MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static unsafe bool IsSameSign(float val1, float val2)
{
   return *(int*)(&val1) >> 31 == *(int*)&val2 >> 31;
}
```

I did some benchmarks against your original version, for your amusement. I run each test 50 times with 100,000 comparisons, and 1,000,000 respectively

```
Test Framework : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Scale : 100000
Name          |       Time |     Delta |  Deviation |      Cycles
-----------------------------------------------------------------
MySameSign    |   1.045 ms |  0.052 ms |       0.20 |   3,498,252
BaseSameSign  |  15.391 ms |  0.548 ms |       0.81 |  52,181,763


Scale : 1000000
Name          |        Time |     Delta |  Deviation |       Cycles
-------------------------------------------------------------------
MySameSign    |   10.000 ms |  0.232 ms |       0.31 |   33,995,263
BaseSameSign  |  146.250 ms |  1.311 ms |       1.13 |  498,064,434
```

**Example data**

```
static float NextFloat()
{
   double mantissa = (_rand.NextDouble() * 2.0) - 1.0;
   double exponent = Math.Pow(2.0, _rand.Next(-126, 128));
   return (float)(mantissa * exponent);
}
public static List<Tuple<float,float>> GenerateSignInput(int scale)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, scale)
                     .Select(x => new Tuple<float, float>(NextFloat(), NextFloat()))
                     .ToList();
}
```